# Network Adapter no longer detected after graphics card removal?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, network-adapter

Last night, I noticed that my crossfire wasn't working properly. I did some tests and found that all my games run much faster and at lower temperatures without it. So I decided I'd give my extra card to my girlfriend for her computer.

I disabled crossfire, shutdown, gently removed the bridge and second card, then rebooted. The computer booted slowly and Windows 8.1 did some sort of device loading on the first boot. When I finally got to desktop I was no longer connected to the internet so I went looking at the device manager which no longer listed the network adapter anywhere (not even as an unknown device).

I started reading and I really didn't find anything worth while. I tried repairing my network adapter drivers and during installation it said no network adapter was found.

The network adapter is built-into the motherboard. Could this be just a software issue or has it fried on the motherboard?

I've tried:

- Uninstalling the graphics drivers
- Putting original setup back in (after uninstalling drivers :/)
- Reinstalling the graphics drivers
- Repairing the network adapter drivers

Ultimately I'd like to know if this is a software or hardware issue causing this since I don't want to reformat and everything just to find it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Does Windows see the network adapter in Device Manager? Even as an unknown device?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: And if you boot into BIOS, can it see the NIC, on a hardware level?

Comment: Is there a typical location this information is? I looked around and it only have generalized options like "LAN PXE boot" and "OnBoard LAN Card" (options for both are just disabled/enabled respectively). The LAN card doesn't show up on the boot menu (but I personally can't say whether or not it ever has).